# Why does my R loop return an out of bounds error?

Tags: r, loops, discogs-api

I'm trying to write a looped function that extracts data from the discogs api.
I've started with writing a function 'a' and it works:

```
releases <- list()
artists <- list()
artistURL <- "https://api.discogs.com/artists/"

a <- function(artistcode){
  for(i in 0:3){

  artistset <- fromJSON(paste0(artistURL, artistcode, "/releases?page=", i))
  message("Retrieving page ", i)

  releases[[i+1]] <- (as.data.frame(artistset$releases.main_release))
  artists[[i+1]] <- (as.data.frame(artistset$releases.artist ))
}
  return(artistset)
  message("Total rows=", dim(artistset[[2]])[1] )
}
x <- a(135872)
```

Next, I'd like to now add this function into a loop the grabs data for a set of artists who are included in a dataframe, like this:

```
artistdf <- structure(list(
    name = c("Hank Mobley", "Benny Green", "Oscar Peterson", "Art Tatum"), 
    artistcode = c(135872,96442, 254394, 265634)
), .Names = c("name", "artistcode"), row.names = c(NA,-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

for (j in 0:nrow(artistdf)){
    a(artistdf[[j+1, 2]])
}
```

This is where I get an 'out of bounds' error. I've used some debugging advice, but to no avail.  Can anyone offer a solution?

Comment: `[[` can only take one index because it extracts. To index by row and column use `[`.

Comment: Also, `return` exits the function, so anything after it in the function body won't run.

Comment: @alistaire thank you, but i'm still left with an error; any further ideas?

Comment: What line is actually erroring? Do you get a traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be two issues.

First, where you create the artistdf tibble, you're passing "row.names = c(NA,-5L)," which is creating an object with 5 rows although you only have 4 rows of data.  Change this to c(NA, -4L).

Second, starting your final for loop at 0 is creating an issue.  I don't know why that is, but change it as follows:

```
jazzdata <- list()
for (j in 1:nrow(artistdf)){
    jazzdata[[j]] <- a(artistdf[[j, 2]])
}
jazzdata[2] # data are here
```

With these two changes, I was able to get your code to work.

Comment: thanks!  the code works with your changes, but i'm getting a `NULL` result. Any idea why?  I used `jazz4<-for (j in 1:nrow(artistdf)){
  a(artistdf[j, 2])`  removing the double brackets (double brackets didn't work either)

Comment: Try this.  First define jazz4 as an empty list: jazz4 <- list().  Then, in your for loop, use jazz4[[ j ]] <- a(artistdf[[j, 2]]).  You should get a jazz4 object that consists of a list of lists that you can process.

Comment: That works!  Do you want to include this as the final answer?     `jazzdata<-list();`

`for (j in 1:nrow(artistdf)){
  jazzdata[[ j ]] <- a(artistdf[[j, 2]]) 
  }`

`jazzdata[2] # data are here`